# Using Class-Based Views with Function-Based Views together in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

Is it possible to use Class-Based Views with Function-Based Views together in django project?
If yes, Is that best practice ?
Can I use them together in the same *views.py*

Comment: Yes you can use these together and in the same `views.py`. Usually one picks a CBV if there is a base CBV that implements the scenario, and for more sophisticated views an FBV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely you can combine them. Class-based views are great for basic functionalities like crud operations. for more advanced operations you could override subclasses for class-based views but I think you would be better of using function based views for that, especially since its easier to understand for beginners.